# How to ge the search engine name from a web page using javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to identify the search engine using javascript? Say for example if the site has been displayed using the google search, I should get the value as google, similarly yahoo,bing etc.. Is there any written js code for doing so?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_referrer.asp

Answer (score 2):

In general you can use [Google analytics](https://analytics.google.com/).

In JavaScript , you can use `document.referrer`:

> Returns the URI of the page that linked to this page.
>
> ...
>
> The value is an empty string if the user navigated to the page
>   directly (not through a link, but, for example, via a bookmark). Since
>   this property returns only a string, it does not give you DOM access
>   to the referring page.